# No Space on Internal Hardrive C: want to run computer through external hardrive :D

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, boot-camp

Okay so I have the newest Macbook Pro, and I made a windows partition a minute ago with I forgot how much storage but definitely not enough. Every time I want to download something it says C:/User/J1/... ect
"There is not enough space on the disk." However, I have set everything up to download directly to my external 3 TB hard drive (which nothing ever directly downloads to it even though I have it set to do that) but when I download stuff it still says that I have no space on the disk C: when im trying to make everything directly download to the D: drive. I don't know if there is a way to copy all the Program x86 files and main files like that to the external hard drive so I can run windows through the D: drive instead but I have been searching for a way to do it for so long and have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix your "download to D:" issue, sorry - that's entirely a Windows problem, not Mac.

Windows will not boot from an external disk, so that's out.

The only Apple-supported way to change the size of a Boot Camp volume is to erase it & start over. Third parties have made apps to fill this gap.
[TwoCanoes' Winclone](https://twocanoes.com) and [Paragon's CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/#for_mac) are both designed to do this.

Don't attempt to resize the Windows partition from inside Windows.